# GROUP BY with join

Tags: mysql

Here is a query which join another table.

I need to get the total amount of invoices where a text string occurs

`invoice` can have many `invoice_product`

```
SELECT count(i.id)
FROM `invoice` i
INNER JOIN `invoice_product` ip ON ip.invoice_id=i.id
WHERE i.block_id=1 && (i.txt LIKE '%str%' || ip.name LIKE '%str%' || ip.txt LIKE '%str%')
GROUP BY i.id
```

Comment: are you getting any error message?

Comment: no.. but wrong result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count `distinct` ids to get the number of invoices, otherwise you get the total number of rows (after joining). Also you want to aggregate over all invoices (so you don't need a `group by`):

```
SELECT count(distinct i.id)
FROM `invoice` i
INNER JOIN `invoice_product` ip ON ip.invoice_id = i.id
WHERE i.block_id = 1 
  AND (i.txt LIKE '%str%' OR ip.name LIKE '%str%' OR ip.txt LIKE '%str%');
```

Comment: This has a performance issue due to "Inflate (JOIN), then Deflate (DISTINCT or GROUP BY)".

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to run faster, especially as the tables grow:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `invoice` i
WHERE block_id = 1 
  AND (txt LIKE '%str%'
       OR EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `invoice_product` 
                     WHERE invoice_id = i.id
                       AND ( name LIKE '%str%'
                          OR txt LIKE '%str%' )
      )          );
```